# Creating menus links for displaying articles with specific tags

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

How would you go about creating a categorization system which categorizes after tags and then displays a link to the page with only the specific tags linked/posted?

Aka 1 page per category. On each page there is series of blog-posts/content which has the same tag (I believe this is called the taxonomy term?)

and then of course add the links to the pages to the menu (got this one as long as there is an URL)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Transforms your taxonomy vocabularies into menus with ease!
>
> Features:
>
> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with Views
> - Integrate with Pathauto: use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules